# T4 template for VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, uml, t4

What would be the best way to create T4 template for VB in visual studio 2013?

I have tried to convert the CSharp ones to VB but keep getting these errors, which I have no idea how to resolve.

Errors I have been getting -->(ScreenShot) https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjDl5.png

I am using Devart T4 Editor extension in visual studio ultimate 2013

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What has this got to do with UML?

Comment: Can you list the exact steps you're taking to get to the state you describe/screenshot?

Comment: @ThomasKilian visual studio uses those templates to generate code from UML diagrams.

Comment: @Sasfrog all I did was take the pre compiled t4 template for csharp that comes with visual studio, first changed the template language to vb and then started converting the code to vb syntax. 
Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @ThomasKilian Here's a link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx about generating code from UML diagrams